# Decompiling and recompiling frameworks.jar in android stock rom

Tags: java, android

I came across a situation where i have to put some debug logs inside some code methods of PackageInstaller.java in my stock ROM.

> https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageInstaller.java

I found that file is deodexed in classes.dex file inside frameworks.java of system folder in the ROM folder. I came across that decompilation will give me the java files (not completely 100% accuracy in code content). So I expects= that these incomplete code base will make blocking in my stock ROM functionality.

So i thought of grabbing a seperate module from this will give me a 100% code base.

> https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base

So the question is how can I make this git repo to build a new frameworks.jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Compile the repo into a jar file, using usual compilation methods in terminal (CLI).

Or you could even try the docs part in the repo link. The HTML files in the ***docs folder*** will surely help you execute the repo.